# Class Decorators that accept arguments

Tags: python-2.7, python-decorators

I have been trying to understand this class decorator:

```
class MyClassDecorator:
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        self.conf_args = a
        self.conf_kw = kw

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

@MyClassDecorator('arg1')
def mysum(x,y):
    return x+y
```

after decoration mysum becomes an object of MyDecoratorClass via this:

```
mysum = MyDecorator('arg1')(mysum)
```

then how does it accepts arguments, as mysum becomes **call** following above protocol and it accepts only one argument the func itself, i.e how the variable passed to mysum get passed to the call function?? please enlighten me, there is lack of material on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
mysum = MyDecorator('arg1')(mysum)
```

the first step will be: 
`Mydecorator('arg1')`, this gives a decorator object, which immediately gets called with mysum function. The **call** responds and returns 
wrapper function which takes arguments *args, and **kwargs. This is how the arguments are available. so in essence, mysum(x,y) got replaced by wrapper(*args, 
**kwargs)